# Tracking Code Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

This is my very first question here.

I am very new to Prestashop.
I am trying to install a tracking code for an affiliate program that allows me to retrieve info from the order-confirmation page (that's where the code will be embedded) . this is the affiliate tracking code, do you know with what parameters i should replace the parameters inside the '    '. What are the variables for this in prestashop?
Thanks very much for your kind answers

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
/*** Do not change ***/
var AWIN = {};
AWIN.Tracking = {};
AWIN.Tracking.Sale = {};

/*** Set your transaction parameters ***/
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.amount = 'SALE_AMOUNT';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.currency = 'GBP';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.orderRef = 'ORDER_REF';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = 'COMMISSION_GROUP:SALE_AMOUNT';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.voucher = 'VOUCHER_CODE';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = '1';
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this article: http://wiki.affiliatewindow.com/index.php/Merchant_Tracking_Guide ?

Example from it:

```
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.amount = '100.00';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.currency = 'GBP';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.orderRef = '123456';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = 'DVD:25.00|VIDEO:25.00|CD:25.00|BOOK:25.00';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.voucher = 'BOOK_VOUCHER1';
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = '0';
```

Comment: Yes , this is precisely where I have copied the code that needs to be embedded. My question here, is how to replace the numbers with the correct values, that is the VARIABLES used by prestashop to pass on these values on to the script. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the me-in-the-past person: what you're trying to solve here is modifying javascript code in a template file: make sure to output these values in between brackets and transform the template output into javascript data so that the above code can send correct info.